# Is it possible to ensure n-matches to a search in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out how to implement the following in Elasticsearch, and feel as though I have read documentation before on how to do it but can no longer find it.

I have 3 fields I will be searching on; profileIds, title, and description.

For profile ids I'm just searching for an exact term match, which is trivial enough.

I will be having a list of phrases to match against title and description, but I only want to match if there's a total of 3 or more matches with any keyword against the title or description (it doesn't have to be the same keyword on the same field).

I get that I should have a nested Or query setup like so: (matches profile ids, (has 3 matches on title OR description for any of the keywords)) but the part I am struggling with is saying "3 matches".

Is this possible in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-bool-query.html)  together with [terms query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and using `minimum_should_match`.

Example:

```
{
  "query": {
     "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
              "term": {
                 "profile_ids": {
                    "value": "42"
                 }
              }
           }
        ],
        "should": [
           {
              "terms": {
                 "title": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
                 "minimum_should_match": 3
              }
           },
           {
              "terms": {
                 "description": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
                 "minimum_should_match": 3
              }
           }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
     }
  }
}
```

So both of the `terms` queries must match on at least 3 keywords. And then one of those two should match while the `profile_ids` must always match.

Note that if you have less than 3 keywords the `terms` query will match if all terms match.

Comment: After rereading the question I see this is not entirely correct. The requirement is total of 3 matches in both fields, not 3 matches in one of the two fields. I'll leave it for now, it might still be helpful.